# Joomla Not Usinsg Alias?

Tags: joomla, seo, http-status-code-404, joomla-sef-urls, broken-links

I just transferred a Joomla website over to a new server and for some reason I cannot follow any of the links - they lead to 404 / index.php not found. I have my SEF and URL rewriting enabled and I am using alias in my menus etc. If I use the preview link that's in the menu to view an article - that shows up fine. No matter what page I make default - it will show up fine but when I navigate the menus I get 404. First thing I thought was that something might be wrong with my `.htaccess` but that also looks fine:

**.htaccess**

```
##
# @package      Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2012 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Next I checked my sql file I uploaded (I did change the DB-Prefix) but all that looks fine. My config looks fine - it's able to open the Default page no matter what default menu item I pick. What other problems could cause 404s?

**Edit**

404 page reads:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Comment: Can you put the text of the 404 error in your question usually it will give a clue.

Comment: Ok that's a pretty basic apache 404, it doesn't appear to be a Joomla! style 404 - do you have a URL we can check? (As I'm thinking you may have a browser/dns resolution caching issue).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the URL and the .htaccess it appears the website you've linked to is actually in a sub-directory.

If this is the case the `RewriteBase /` line will be a problem as it's pointing to the severs root not the Joomla! installation root. Try fixing that line with the right path then the requests should actually be passed through the Joomla! `index.php`

Comment: When setting the base you only need to point to the directory not the index file.

Answer (score 1):

I had my joomla installation at `/var/www/test`, and the RewriteBase (in .htaccess) was pointed at `/` (which is `/var/www`). Got it working after I changed it to `/test`.